# The gap between IEEE bibliography and main text

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, gap

So this is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    \section{Acknowledgements}
    \label{sec:acknowledgements}
    The authors would like to thank....for their valuable advice and recommendations that helped improve the quality of the paper. 
    \begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{image_file}}]
    {Eyck van Denesle} is a Lecturer at Oxenfurt University. For several years he has been working on the application of sharp weapons to monsters. Email:evd@oxenfurt.ac.re 
    \end{IEEEbiography}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEETran}
    \bibliography{main} \end{document}
```

I don't like the result, because of the gap between Acknowledgements and bibliography (almost a whole column). Various `\hspace` and `\skip` commands didn't work.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` helps.  If you drop the [keepaspectratio] you will see that the space is needed for the photo.

Comment: well I use it, and setting  keepaspectratio=False  doesn't fix the problem

Comment: It wasn't supposed to fix the problem.  It was supposed show you why the gap is there.